# Read from Java standard input without polling or constantly reading and without wasting resources

Tags: java

If a program sends data to my standard input stream in Java through a pipe, how can I make my Java program atuomatically detect if new data is coming through the pipe into the input stream so that I can read it?

I know that I could use an infinite while loop that constantly keeps reading and checking the standard input stream. But this is inefficent and it takes a lot of resources. I am not even allowed to do this for my assignment.

It has to be synchronized somehow. Can I put a listener on the pipe or standard input that says: "Hey! Read the standard input now! New data is coming!" or can I make the pipe send interrupts or how do I do this?

Comment: Could someone come up with NIO solution?

Comment: Reading in an infinite loop isn't inefficient, and it doesn't waste resources. It blocks until data is available. Nothing wasted at all, and nothing inefficient about it. I suggest you post the actual terms of the assignment here. It doesn't appear that you've understood them.

Comment: There are several NIO solutions that implement UDP streams with channel futures (async callbacks), Netty for example. 
A reactor pattern is used for the stream read.
Also look at Protobuf for efficient serialization.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is no way to check to see if input is available from an `InputStream` (or `Reader`) that doesn't either block the current thread ... or involve expensive polling.

The simple solution is just to attempt the read, and block until data arrives.  This solution is OK **unless** ...

- you want to do other things while waiting for the data to arrive, or
- the data might arrive on one of many input streams.

In such cases, you either need to use NIO selectors (which allow you to wait until data arrives on one of a set of streams, or use a different thread for reading the data from each stream, and other threads for processing it (or doing other things).  In the latter case, you probably need some kind of queueing mechanism to pass "messages" from the reader thread / threads to the processing thread / threads.

However, the bottom line is that we can't offer a good concrete solution without more details of your application.

---

One piece of advice: don't try to use the `InputStream.available()` or `Reader.ready()`.  These involve polling ... and their specified semantics are such that that can't tell you definitively if a `read` *will* block.  They are basically useless ...

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this is to use the `read` method on the inputstream?
If the data is text then you may use the `readLine` method.

See this informative [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/10/06/how-to-read-data-from-inputstream-into-string-in-java/)

Of course, the tread that is calling this code will block, so it would ideally this code would be in a different thread.

Comment: @Basilevs I have updated my answer to highlight this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Simply saying, **There ain't no such thing as a free lunch** :D

If you are asking for synchronous messages, someone else would have to poll for it if not you. So basically, there should have been no impact on performance if such synchronous (or event driven) system existed. (Unless operating system itself does it with some performance benefits).

Nonetheless, when we are talking about java standard input stream, the contracts between program, jvm and os are already decided. So just to answer your question, you'll have to poll (in a new thread if you like).

Hope this helps.